# First (entered) node is not getting printed

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

In my linked list program, the first entered data is not getting printed, it is the first time I am making any program using pointers to pointers. And also please tell me if I have used pointers to pointers in right manner.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int i;
    struct node *next; 
};

void arrange(struct node **x_head,struct node **x_temp)
{
    (*x_temp)->next=*x_head;
    *x_head=*x_temp;
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head, *temp;
    char c;
    printf("Do you want to enter data? Y/N ");
    scanf(" %c",&c);
    if((c=='Y')||(c=='y'))
    {
        head=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter your data: ");
        scanf(" %d",&head->i);
        head->next=NULL;
        printf("Do you want to enter data? Y/N ");
        scanf(" %c",&c);
    }
    while((c=='Y')||(c=='y'))
    {
        temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->next=NULL;
        printf("Enter your data: ");
        scanf(" %d",&temp->i);
        arrange(&head,&temp);
        printf("Do you want to enter data? Y/N ");
        scanf(" %c",&c);
    }
    temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->i);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're overwriting the head pointer with temp, and thus losing reference to the top of your linked list.

Comment: It works: https://ideone.com/sckwpm It only misses on the last element which I fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert the nodes at the head, so you don't miss the first node, but the last in the list when you print it, because you test whether the node after the current one is null:

```
         while (temp->next!=NULL) ...
```

Note that this will fail (or crash, rather) if your list is empty. Thest the current node for null:

```
         temp=head;

         while (temp != NULL) {
             printf("%d ",temp->i);
             temp = temp->next;
         }
```

(Note that when you insert nodes at the head, you don't need a special case when the head is null; just set the new node's `next` to the olod head, which is null.)